# Short German word for spending the holidays at home

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Today I saw the English word *stay-cation* (holidays spent at home) and marveled at its shortness and precision to describe a holiday spent at home or doing sightseeing in your hometown.

In German I only know *Urlaub auf Balkonien.* Are there other, preferably shorter words or clever portmanteaus to describe it? *Heimurlaub* sounds too military. *Hausurlaub* sounds too much like *house arrest. Heimreise* already has a different meaning.

Comment: Kürzer wäre "Urlaub daheim", aber das ist nicht so griffig wie "Balkonien".

Comment: What came to mind when I read the title was suggested by you in the body of the question. I can't remember having ever heard anything other than "Balkonien".

Comment: Shorten "Urlaub auf Balkonien" to "Balkonien" only. Everyone will know what you're talking about. And I don't think it gets any shorter (It is already shorter than *staycation*).

Comment: Come on, for German language "Urlaub auf Balkonien" is not long. I've never heard "Heimurlaub", but "Heimaturlaub" is a common word. However, it means something different: If you are living in an other city and visiting the town where you grow up/your parents live, that is called "Heimaturlaub".

Comment: @tofro: Since -ien is an ending typically representing a country (Tunesien, Arabien, Tschechien, Brasilien, Argentinien), I'd would vote for *in Balkonien* instead of *auf* (which implies, that it is the name of an island).

Comment: Bad Meingarten ist äquivalent zu Balkonien.

Comment: @Iris "Heimaturlaub" bekommt eher der Soldat an der Front als der Balkonienurlauber.

Comment: @guidot I guess, people use "_auf_ Balkonien" because they are "_auf_ dem Balkon", not "_im_ Balkon"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your question, I research a little bit if there are other words than the ones, you have already written. What I have found is *Urlaub zu Hause*.

I also found an [article](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/reise/rainer-erlinger-14375394.html) about this topic and the author of the article likes the word *Stay(va)cation* and he meant that there is no corresponding word in German.

### Edit

I do not know whether it is meant joke but there is also another word, similar to Balkonien. It is *Terrassien*. For difference of these words, please see the comment of "Tom-OliverHeidel" below.

Comment: I will explain 'Balkonien' and 'Terrassien' shortly. The first word comes from 'Balkon' (engl. balcony) which refers mostly to people living in a city (hope it is obvious why especially in contrast with the next word). The next one is coming from 'Terrasse' (engl. terrace) this one refers to people living in houses or in rural regions. Both words are somehow made up [words] tho being in the duden. In my knowledge those saying were common before 2000 and more used in the east. @Ad Infinitum ich weiß, dass du Deutscher bist. Nur als Zusatz für andere.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel Thank you very much for your addition. No, I am not German :) but I learn German language with passion..

Comment: Accepted as an answer, although "Hierlaub" and the other suggestions by @Crissov are also very nice.

Comment: @chiborg I think the suggestions of Crissov were imaginary and they are not used in everyday language.

Answer (score 4):

Spending vacation at home is not unusual even for Germans who are known to travel a lot. Close to the English example *staycation* we may hear of a German's travel to a ficitional country *[Balkonien](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Balkonien)* used as a joke. It means we "travel" to our own balcony.

But this is not used too often. Mostly we would just say:

> Wir bleiben hier.
>   Wir fahren nicht fort.
>   Wir bleiben daheim.

Comment: I would disagree that "Balkonien" is seldomly used. I hear it very often and not just as joke but as an idiom.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach *not too often* != *seldom* ;)

Comment: As an anecdote: In Switzerland, we have UHU Ferien, which means "ums huus ume", which translates to "Um's Haus herum".

Comment: @SBI nice - I guess it doesn't get any shorter than that. But also not anymore cryptic ;)

Comment: Ever been to Rundumhausen?

Comment: Balkonien is a very common word here in my environment. Take away the "no used often" and I will upvote, as thats the one for me...

Comment: @acdhirr It's called _Rundhausen_ in Twente, which is in the east of Holland.

Answer (score 0):

*Sparen* refers not necessarily to vacation but is short and at least a possible answer to

> Was macht ihr dieses Jahr im Urlaub?

**Think result**

Since no short german word for *staycation* seems to exist we have to build one too:

> Bleiben + Urlaub = Blurlaub

This is the new normal.

Comment: You might want to revise this answer as it doesn't look like an answer to me...

Comment: @tofro: Thinking ...

Comment: As for portmanteaux and other neologisms or puns other than _Balkonien_, I’d go with something like _Ferhierien_, _Hierlaub_, _Urfürlaub/Fürlaub_, _El Sparenal_, _Sparien_, _Hierkei_, _Vordertürkei_, _Karhierbik_, _Nahreise_, _Fernsehreise_, _Heimtel_, _Costa Nixa_, _Lago di Baggero_, _(Stadt-/Kur-)Parkistan_, _Stadtteilrand statt Thailand_, _Autobahnkreuzfahrt_, _Couchingtrip_, _Sofari_ …

Comment: @Crissov +1 for hierlaub :)

Comment: … _(Schreber-)Garteneriffa, Südfriesland / südfriesische Inseln, Aldiven, FKK-Urlaub = Fahren keinen Kilometer_ … @AdInfinitum Ich fand _Vordertürkei_ und _Sofari_ eigentlich am besten.

Comment: hahah Sofari ist auch sehr gut..

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Balkonienurlaub would be a reasonable option.

Comment: Better just say `wir verbringen unseren Urlaub auf Balkonien` (we will spend our holiday in Balkonien)

Comment: That sounds great, except the OP was asking for a short word - yours is anything but short! ;)